# rails_admin has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have has_and_belongs_to_many relation in my models. I have relation beetween models Hotels and HotelRoomsTypes

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible hotel_room_types_attributes    
    has_and_belongs_to_many :hotel_room_types,:class_name => "HotelRoomType"
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :hotel_room_types, :allow_destroy => true
end

class HotelRoomType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :hotels
end
```

when I am trying create association in rails_admin, I see following markup:
[image]

after creation, rails_admin doesn't show associations to those model. Anybody solved those problem or found patch to rails_admin?

Answer (score 0):

I had downgraded from rails_admin 0.4.9 to 0.4.1 and problem solves.

You can track progress of solution here:
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1737